# Spring Data Couchbase Object id

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to create a Document with an `@Id` property different from `String`, everything works great. My issue is the way the document is stored in the **Bucket**, unfortunately it prefixes with the Class name:

`ActorKey(key=d7471027-4bd1-40a3-8e29-5249f45beed4)`

```
{
  "name": "Emma Watson",
  "_class": "com.guilherme.miguel.domain.Actor"
}
```

Is there a way to store the id like if it was a simple `String`?
This is to avoid issues in plain queries (simple queries will force me to use **ActorKey(key=xxxxxxxxxxx)**)

**Actor.java**:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Actor {

  @Id
  private ActorKey key;
  private String name;

}
```

**ActorKey.java**:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ActorKey implements Serializable {

  private String key;

}
```

**ActorRepository.java**

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "actor")
public interface ActorRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Actor, ActorKey> {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying Couchbase SDK uses `String` as a Document identifier, so spring-data-couchbase will call `toString()` on your key objects. What you see is the result of the [Lombok-generated](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString.html) `toString()` method (a generation that is part of the `@Data` annotation).

Simply explicitly override `toString()` in `ActorKey`!